# Converting GeoJSON object to Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, geojson

I need to convert a GeoJSON output from a server to a Javascript array; I have done some searches and they were for the 'regular' JSON outputs and not the GeoJSON. Here is the output from the Server:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","property":"blah"}, {"type":"Feature","property":"blah2"}]}
```

And here is what I need (note, no quotation on the 'features' variable needed):

```
features = [{"type":"Feature","property":"blah"}, {"type":"Feature","property":"blah2"}]}
```

I think I need to find the 'features' property and then loop through its objects? Thanks!

Comment: So you have a valid JSON string, and you want to convert it to something that is not valid ?

Comment: `features = JSON.parse('{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","property":"blah"}, {"type":"Feature","property":"blah2"}]}').features`

Comment: I need to convert to a standard Javascript array for something in my javascript code; the regular (valid) GeoJSON is being used fine in some other part of the code. Thanks.

Comment: @Malk: I need to do in a loop--can't hard code the values. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A GeoJSON object is still a JSON object (it's the first thing their documentation says).

http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html

If you want to store the features PROPERTY of a GeoJSON object, access the property value as you would normally after conversion to a javascript object and push that property into a new variable, or use as is.

```
var geoObject = JSON.parse(geoJSONObject);
var features = [];

features = geoObject.features;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. But gettting an error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
geoObject = JSON.parse(geoJsonData);

Comment: Answer accepted! I think all I had to do was: features = geoJsonData.features; [no JSON.parse needed]. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, the geoJSON object wasn't even JSON then, it was already a javascript object :)

Comment: Hey so finally getting somewhere with this solution after hours... :-) anyone know how to get the properties in the array, i tried features = geoObject.features.properties, but that didn't work. Work for features array, but I want to go one more deeper and get all the properties???

Comment: ok, so I got it in case anyone else needs it:  

var features = [];
features = json.features;

var jproperties = json.features.map(function (el) {
            return el.properties;
 });

Comment: I ran into a problem where it wasn't valid due to exporting from QGIS as newline delimited, which is just json entries without a valid json wrapper.